# How to format xml or html's attributes into multiple lines instead of lining up on one line?

Tags: formatting, filetype-xml

I'm using plugin [Chiel92/vim-autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) auto formatting xml files. So the default format program used for xml file is `tidy`. The way it formats xml file is like below:

```
<List id='list' items='{/sss}' mode='{device&gt;/listMode}' noDataText='{i18n&gt;masterListNoDataText}' select='onSelect' growing='true' growingScrollToLoad='true'>
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem type='{device&gt;/listItemType}' press='onSelect' title='{Name}' number='{ path: "Price", formatter: "exp.ind.cli.util.Formatter.currencyValue" }' numberUnit='USD'></ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

As you can see the attributes of the tags are on one line, and it can last very long even goes out of the screen. What I want is all the attributes to be formatted on separate lines( vertically aligned ).

```
<List id='list' 
    items='{/sss}' 
    mode='{device&gt;/listMode}' 
    noDataText='{i18n&gt;masterListNoDataText}' 
    select='onSelect' 
    growing='true' 
    growingScrollToLoad='true'>

    <items>
        <ObjectListItem type='{device&gt;/listItemType}' 
                    press='onSelect' 
                    title='{Name}' 
                    number='{ path: "Price", formatter: "exp.ind.cli.util.Formatter.currencyValue" }' 
                    numberUnit='USD'>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

I think it makes easier to spot the attributes and improve the readability of the xml file. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: "vim is not formatting them correctly" No, Vim formats them *correctly*. What it doesn't do is format them *how you want*. For that you will need to find a specialized command-line xml formatter and use it from Vim either with `:!<external command>` or with `:help 'formatprg'` or `:help equalprg`.

Comment: It's automatic code format I'm talking about. Even if I manually type a line break, after auto xml format, everything goes back to the original format.

Comment: What are you using to automatically format the xml?

Comment: I'm not clear what is vim currently automatically formatting xml, I installed the Chiel92/vim-autoformat plugin, and I think for xml files, it will use "tidy" program bundled with mac os to format it.

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting down votes. Does anyone have a solution for this problem? or I'm just the only one who wants this?

Comment: The problem with your original question is that you didn't really describe what you did. You just said "not formatting them correctly", with no mention of what commands you used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should *almost* work, it aligns the attributes slightly different than your example, but it's probably "close enough":

```
autocmd FileType xml let g:formatprg_args_expr_xml .= '." --indent-attributes 1"'
```

Which will format it like as:

```
<List id='list'
      items='{/sss}'
      mode='{device&gt;/listMode}'
      noDataText='{i18n&gt;masterListNoDataText}'
      select='onSelect'
      growing='true'
      growingScrollToLoad='true'>
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem type='{device&gt;/listItemType}'
                        press='onSelect'
                        title='{Name}'
                        number='{ path: "Price", formatter: "exp.ind.cli.util.Formatter.currencyValue" }'
                        numberUnit='USD'></ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

Now, figuring this out was actually quite easy :-) Here's what I did:

1. I looked at the [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) homepage to see how it formatted XML files, and it says: *"`tidy` for XHTML and XML"*.
2. So, we need to see if the `tidy` tool supports formatting the attributes like you want. After installing `tidy`, I ran `tidy -h` to see the help for this program. This told me that `-help-config` lists all configuration options, so I ran that:

   ```
   $ tidy -help-config
   ```

   This gave me a very long list, so I put the output in Vim:

   ```
   $ tidy -help-config | vim -
   ```
3. Since we want to do something with *attributes*, I used `/attr` to search for that, and after pressing `n` once I get:

   ```
   indent-attributes           Boolean    y/n, yes/no, t/f, true/false, 1/0
   ```

   I have no idea what this does, but it looks like it might be what we want?
4. Let's try adding this option. I went back to the vim-autoformat homepage, and noticed the *"How can I change the behaviour of formatters, or add one myself?"* section, which is how I figured out how to add the above option (this is the only part that required some effort, since the section isn't brilliantly written).

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker, thanks for even teaching me how to find solution for problems. It's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested solution didn't work for me. `formatprg_args_expr_xml` is no longer recognized in the current version (at [713e7c2](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat/tree/713e7c258052d94dfd752647ea03cf423cace8ff)).

I solved the issue by adding these two lines in my `.vimrc`.

```
let g:formatdef_fmt_custom_xml = '"tidy -xml -q --show-errors 0 --show-warnings 0 --indent-attributes 1"'
let g:formatters_xml = ['fmt_custom_xml']
```

Of course I had to make sure tidy is already installed and present in my `$PATH`.